# shifting a binary number to the right in assembly with SAR vs. SHR

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bit-shift

We know that when we shift a binary number to the right, it is divided by 2.
For the number: `1001 0001`. Let's assume that is stored in `AX` register:

- If we consider it as unsigned number (which is equal to `145` in decimal): 
  `SHR AX, 1` will make `AX` equal to `0100 1000` which is equal to `72` in decimal, and this is right.
- But if we consider it as signed number (which is equal to `-111` in decimal): `SAR AX, 1` will make `AX` equal to `1100 0100` which is equal to `-56` in decimal, and this is wrong because it should be equal to `-55` in decimal.

Why?

Comment: @ delnan @ Jarhmander
Thank you. I understand that when we do logical shift then we are dividing by 2 and the fraction is ignored in the result, and when we do arithmetic shift then we are dividing by 2 and the result is rounded towards minus infinity.

Comment: What makes you think it's “wrong” and it should be -55? The binary value `1100 0100` **does** correspond to -56; the binary value of -55 is `1100 1001`.

Comment: @OndrejTucny That what I wrote. 1100 0100 = -56 but I thought that it should equal -55.

Comment: Maybe my answers provides you with an explation of the detailed behavior of SHR/SAR.

Comment: Thank you although I know that already.

Comment: ammarx, actually, there were a lot of talks about negative numbers on computers before we settled for what it is today. To be symmetrical, -1 should be `1111 1110` This way, `1000 0000` would be -127. The problem with that method is that `0000 0000` and `1111 1111` would both represent zero (like with floating points you would have +0 and -0...). Instead we have numbers from -128 to +127 which is asymmetrical as you just found out.

Comment: How `0000 0000` and `1111 1111` both represent 0? This is the case when we use 1's complement in representing signed numbers. Here we are using 2's complement and `1111 1111` is equal to `-1` and `1111 1110` is `-2'.

Answer (score 5):

The `SHR` instruction performs an unsigned shift rights, shifting in zeros:

```
Input:  1001 0001
        |      |\
        +------+ +--> lost
            v
         +------+
         |      |
Output: 0100 1000
        ^
        +-- added by SHR
```

On the other hand, the `SAR` instruction performs a **signed** shift right, interpreting the most significant bit as a sign.  It shifts in copies of the sign bit:

```
Input:  1001 0001
        |      |\
        +------+ +--> lost
        |   v
        |+------+
        v|      |
Output: 1100 1000
        ^
        +-- preserved (copied) by SAR
```

Comment: You could also mention the ROR... Although it is a "rotation" it is always shown as part of the shift instructions.

Comment: @AlexisWilke How is it related to the OPs question? I could also mention SHL, SAL, … and a couple other bitwise operations.

Answer (score 4):

An arithmetic shift right does a divide by 2 that rounds towards minus infinity.

Answer (score 3):

> We know that when we shift a binary number to the right, it is divided by 2

This is where the confusion starts!
`shl shr sal sar` are just shifts - nothing more.  If some kind of shift resembles a division by 2 it's more or less a bonus. We can not call this behaviour right or wrong.

Comment: Originally, I thought WTF is this answer… and then it struck me like lightning, that I almost certainly made an error in the optimization of integer division by constant powers of 2 in an x86 code generator I wrote like 20 years ago! And now, on which archived CD the source code is? :D :D